# What kind of carbon ions exist?

Tags: ions

I think there are $\ce{C^{4-}}$ and $\ce{C^{2-}}$ existing. How can we find the charge of ions in the elements? Should we look at the group or valence?

Comment: Chemistry of group XIV , especially the all notorious Carbon {:)))} is not something with definite clear-cut rules (At least, that's what I have reached with studying this element's properties.) Carbon usually forms Carbocations and not Carbanions. I think it's better for you to do some research yourself rather than directly asking it. That way this broadly answerable question of yours won't be answered with short answers, and you will understand how to deal with C ions better. Hope I've helped.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with your question. Can you give some examples of where you think these ions exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many different carbon ions exist in the gas phase.

In [Electronic spectra of linear carbon anions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301010497003583), spectra of $\ce{C_2^-}$, $\ce{C_3^-}$... $\ce{C_10^-}$ are discussed.

Dianions such as $\ce{C_7^{2-}}$ have also been observed.

In the solid phase, aluminum carbide and berylium carbide have more than 50% ionic character according to the Handbook of Refractory carbides and nitrides, and correspond to $\ce{C^{4-}}$.  Calcium carbide, which could be considered a salt of acetylene, corresponds to  $\ce{C2^{2-}}$  rather than $\ce{C^{2-}}$